# How to convert between custom constant types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I am doing a problem on Exercism.org (specifically [meetup](https://exercism.org/tracks/haskell/exercises/meetup)). To reduce it to a minimal example, I am going to solve a slightly simpler problem that illustrates the same issue.

*Added for context after Daniel's comment:
Exercism has pre-written tests about a data structure it defines (called `Weekday`) inside the file. We can implement it how we like, but the tests use constructors `Monday`, `Tuesday`, etc. I want the implementation to be `DayOfWeek`, which has the same named constructors but more of the behavior. We can argue that Exercism should have used this constructor, but they didn't. It feels like there should be a relatively simple way to take the contract (this thing is named `Weekday` and I can implement how I like, provided I don't change the constructor names) and point it to an already implemented type.*

### The (very short) version of the problem

I have a data type that makes constants, which behaves like a library type. How can I alias my own data type? Specifically, I expect to have

```hs
data Weekday = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
```

and would like to alias this to `Data.Time.Calendar.DayOfWeek` to use well tested code.

## With more context and attempted solution

Pretend this is an Exercism-style problem, where we have the prompt

```hs
module Meetup (Weekday(..), findFirstDay) where

import Data.Time.Calendar (Day)

data Weekday = Monday
             | Tuesday
             | Wednesday
             | Thursday
             | Friday
             | Saturday
             | Sunday

findFirstDay :: Weekday -> Integer -> Int -> Day
findFirstDay weekday year month = error "You have to implement this function"
```

We would be expected to modify this (for example, we probably want `deriving Eq` on the Weekday data type).

An attempt to solve this problem might look like

```hs
import Data.Time.Calendar (Day, fromGregorian, dayOfWeek)

{- Get all [Mondays|Tuesdays|..|Sundays] in the month -}
allWeekdayOfMonth :: DayOfWeek -> Integer -> Int -> [Day]
allWeekdayOfMonth weekday year month = filter (\x -> weekday == dayOfWeek x) [fromGregorian year month day| day<-[1..31] ]

almostFindFirstDay :: DayOfWeek -> Integer -> Int -> Day
almostFindFirstDay weekday year month = head $ allWeekdayOfMonth weekday year month
```

The reason this function isn't the desired one is because the first argument is a different type (`DayOfWeek` vs `Weekday`). Specifically, the tests are written with `Weekday` as an import, so I cannot just switch the datatypes.

My understanding is that this is where I could use a `type` alias, which would make my signatures a little more readable but be invisible to the compiler (e.g. if I wanted to make obvious from the signature what the Int[eger]s represented, I could do `type Month=Int` etc).

So here is my attempt to solve:

```hs
module Meetup (Weekday(..), findFirstDay) where

import Data.Time.Calendar (Day, fromGregorian, dayOfWeek, DayOfWeek(..))

type Weekday = DayOfWeek

allWeekdayOfMonth :: DayOfWeek -> Integer -> Int -> [Day]
allWeekdayOfMonth weekday year month = filter (\x -> weekday == dayOfWeek x) [fromGregorian year month day| day<-[1..31] ]

almostFindFirstDay :: DayOfWeek -> Integer -> Int -> Day
almostFindFirstDay weekday year month = head $ allWeekdayOfMonth weekday year month

findFirstDay :: Weekday -> Integer -> Int -> Day
findFirstDay weekday year month = head $ allWeekdayOfMonth weekday year month
```

This works in `ghci` if I copy everything below the module line:

```
ghci> findFirstDay Monday 2023 11
2023-11-06
```

But when I use the module system on Exercism I get errors like

```
 Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘findFirstDay’:
        Patterns of type ‘DayOfWeek’, ‘Integer’,
                         ‘Int’ not matched:
            Monday (GHC.Num.Integer.IS _) _
            Monday (GHC.Num.Integer.IP _) _
            Monday (GHC.Num.Integer.IN _) _
            Tuesday (GHC.Num.Integer.IS _) _
            ...
```

## Note on what I am not looking for

I am aware that I could use an Enum and the position, a known date, date difference, and modular arithmetic to solve the problem pretty easily. It isn't a case of "what is the algorithm?" but I am surprised how difficult it is to reuse a type that has a different name elsewhere, and looking for the canonical approach to such problems.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something really basic. Why have you defined `Weekday` when `DayOfWeek` already exists and is essentially identical?

Comment: Because the tests on Exercism are expressed in terms of `Weekday`. Why they defined it that way, I am not sure, but they did. Precisely my problem is "these seem essentially identical, can't I do something so I don't have to reimplement?". Note: Added to question text after Daniel's comment to make clearer that Weekday is an "external" dependency.

Comment: I see. The issue here is that exercism used an import list like `import Meetup (Weekday(..))`, which means that if you make `Weekday` a type alias you don't get the associated constructors. That's annoying, but can be worked around with a `newtype` instead (will update my answer shortly).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your client has an import list like this:

```
import Meetup (Weekday(..))
```

In such a case, in order for the `(..)` to import anything, we must make a new type -- a simple `type` alias will not do. This is admittedly a bit obnoxious, and perhaps should be the subject of a GHC language extension. Here's a minimal example of how to make a new type with `newtype`:

```
{-# Language PatternSynonyms #-}
module Meetup (Weekday(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)) where

import qualified Data.Time.Calendar as C

newtype Weekday = Weekday { getDayOfWeek :: C.DayOfWeek }
pattern Monday    = Weekday C.Monday
pattern Tuesday   = Weekday C.Tuesday
pattern Wednesday = Weekday C.Wednesday
pattern Thursday  = Weekday C.Thursday
pattern Friday    = Weekday C.Friday
pattern Saturday  = Weekday C.Saturday
pattern Sunday    = Weekday C.Sunday
```

There are now conversions between this new type and the original one available inside the `Meetup` module:

```
Weekday :: C.DayOfWeek -> Weekday
getDayOfWeek :: Weekday -> C.DayOfWeek
```

The in-memory representations of `Weekday` and `C.DayOfWeek` are guaranteed to be the same -- the conversion functions above will generally disappear in the compiled code, except in special circumstances.